# Are there governance limits on lightning web components

Tags: api, governorlimits, lightning-web-components, aws

Was curious. Client wants us to render data from an external database in a lightning web component data table. In this situation, as a front ender, I would typically just make an API call out from the lightning web component to some AWS REST API and pull in the data to display. In this situation am I going to hit governance limits? I’m hoping because this is all happening client side that I wouldn’t.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LWC has no limits regarding client-side usage. The only governor limits in play are those that you would find in any other Salesforce API (e.g. CPU time, heap limits, etc). Obviously, if the API you are calling has limits, then those limits would be applicable as well, but that's not something Salesforce would enforce.

Comment: I'm surprised that they don't have limit of total number of lwc components too similar to what they had with Apex code size.

Comment: @metasync I was surprised, too. So much so that I asked them directly, just to make sure. That gives us a lot of utility with components.